# Is it secure to have an `initialize` method in the proxy smart contract?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I have a question regarding the `initialize` function, usually found in the upgradable implementation contract as a replacement for the constructor.
My question is that, from a security point of view, are there any caveats of having an `initialize` function in the proxy smart contract as well? It is required for a special use case which I will describe below.

let's suppose we have a `ERC1967Proxy` contract (just an example):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract ERC1967Proxy {
    bytes32 internal constant KEY_IMPLEMENTATION =
        bytes32(0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc);

    constructor(address implementation) payable {
        _setAddress(KEY_IMPLEMENTATION, implementation);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now, in my use case I need to have a constant address for the proxy contract, when deploying the same contract on different blockchain networks. For that I am using the `CREATE2` opcode, given that the deployer's address is also the same on different networks.

In the contract above I need to provide an `implementation` address to deploy the proxy contract. Let's say I did the following:

1. Deploy the implemenation contract on `network_A` and `network_B` using `CREATE2` opcode to have a constant address
2. Deploy the proxy contract on `network_A` and `network_B` using the implementation address (from step 1) via `CREATE2` opcode to have a constant proxy address on both networks
3. Upgrade the implemenatation contract on `network_A` and `network_B`, so now we have a new address for the implementation contract
4. Deploy the upgraded version of the implementation contract on `network_C`, the address of which would be different from the ones deployed on other networks
5. Deploy the proxy contract on `network_C` using the implementation address generated in step 4.

In the scenario mentioned above, in step 5, I would get a different address for the proxy on `network_C` since the `CREATE2` opcode keeps in account the `bytecode` of the proxy contract, which changes with different constructor arguments.

The scenario above can be resolved by using the following proxy contract instead:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import {Initializable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract InitializableERC1967Proxy is Initializable {
    bytes32 internal constant KEY_IMPLEMENTATION =
        bytes32(0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc);

    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize(address implementation) public initializer {
        _setAddress(KEY_IMPLEMENTATION, implementation);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

With the pattern above, we would need to manually initialize the proxy, but at least we don't have to worry about the `bytecode` of the proxy being changed on different networks. Are there any security risks with this pattern?

I have also considered using beacon proxies for such use case, where the implementation contract address would be kept in a beacon contract but, I don't plan to have multiple proxies, so don't know if that is viable or not.